# Laravel ReflectionException When Injecting Dependency

Tags: laravel-4, dependency-injection, dependencies, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm trying to register some event event subscribers in Laravel. I am using IoC to inject the dependencies into the classes, but I can't seem to get it working. This is my `register()` method in my event service provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->events->subscribe($this->app->make('Edcs\Events\AuthEventSubscriber'));
}
```

I've also tried:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->events->subscribe('Edcs\Events\AuthEventSubscriber');
}
```

I'm getting a `ReflectionException` exception when I use this code. My constructor for `AuthEventSubscriber` looks like this:

```
public function __construct(Hash $hash, Auth $auth)
{
    $this->hash = $hash;
    $this->auth = $auth;
}
```

I'm including the correct namespaces in that class too:

```
use Illuminate\Hashing\HasherInterface as Hash;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager as Auth;
```

So I'm guessing the dependencies aren't loaded when the `register()` method is firing - what's the proper method for injecting dependencies into an event subscriber in Laravel? I've also tried using closures and manually building the classes but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I was registering the event incorrectly - using the above methods must try to build the class too early in the request lifecycle. This is the code I'm using now:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->before(function() {
         $this->app->events->subscribe($this->app->make('Edcs\Events\AuthEventSubscriber'));
    });
}
```